# Conversion error using CASE on a varchar column

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to grab information to send to Google Charts for a graph I'm looking at the column `Active` which can be true/false but is set to varchar in my database.

Using this query:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN CONVERT(int, Active) Active = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Active,
    SUM(CASE WHEN CONVERT(int, Active) Active = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Inactive
FROM 
    Events
```

throws this error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'True' to data type int.`

Comment: Why is `Active` not a bit- but varchar-column?

Comment: Convert to bit rather than int and it should work

Comment: @TimSchmelter It should be, but now i have a whole system built, and am afraid of changing the type as it might affect so many other places on my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ints are not booleans.... they are called **bit** in SQL Server. try;

```
SELECT
SUM(CASE WHEN CONVERT(bit, Active) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Active,
SUM(CASE WHEN CONVERT(bit, Active) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Inactive
FROM Events
```

Or just test for your String

```
SELECT
SUM(CASE WHEN Active = 'True' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Active,
SUM(CASE WHEN Active = 'False' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Inactive
FROM Events
```

P.S. Storing Boolean values as String columns is silly... Consider changing the column to be a bit column so you don't even need to convert it

Comment: That gives me `An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'Active'.`

Comment: Thats just because you can't alias your column in a subquery... remove the second Active in the line as mine looks

Comment: Thanks for the edit, that did work. Will accept as soon as 12mins are up. Thank you.

Comment: Do it the other way around, if you need to display `True` convert the `bit` to `string` but don't store it as text in your table.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - Yes.... that is indeed exactly what I suggested by saying 'Consider changing the column to be a bit column'